# Kotlin android database: cannot cast java.lang.String to android.database.Cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm developing a simple note app in Kotlin for Android which uses a simple sqlite database.
I have already written it in java, but now I have some problems in Kotlin, in particular with a single line of code.
This is the **working** java code by which I take the note ID when I click on it on the listview.

```
itemCursor = (Cursor) activity.listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
noteID = itemCursor.getInt(itemCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NOTES_COLUMN_ID));
itemCursor = helper.getNote(noteID);
```

Then this should be the Kotlin code:

```
var itemCursor: Cursor = activity.listView.getItemAtPosition(position) as Cursor  **(error here on this line, look below for it)**
var noteID: Int = itemCursor.getInt(itemCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID))
itemCursor = helper.getNote(noteID)
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   android.database.Cursor

ListView adapter:

```
list_titles = helper.getAllTitles()
lv_adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_titles)
v.listview.adapter = lv_adapter
```

getAllTitles fun:

```
fun getAllTitles(): ArrayList<String> {

    val db = this.readableDatabase
    var titles = ArrayList<String>()

    db.select(TABLE_NAME).parseList(object : MapRowParser<List<String>> {

        override fun parseRow(columns: Map<String, Any?>): ArrayList<String> {


            val obj = columns.getValue(COLUMN_OBJ).toString()

            titles.add(obj)

            return titles
        }
    })


    return titles

}
```

I do not understand why in Kotlin it gives me this ClassCastException error since in Java is all smooth.

Comment: post your ListView adapter also.

Comment: Done, what's the problem in your opinion?

Comment: `getItemAtPosition()` method returns string that is the problem. Can you post same thing in Java also to understand it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fun getAllTitles(): ArrayList<String>` it should be `fun getAllTitles(): ArrayList<Cursor>` if you want `getItemAtPosition()` to return a `Cursor`

Comment: No problem, masc